# Expo - Lost keystore passwords

Tags: android, expo, google-play-console, android-keystore

I built an app using expo. And when I built android app I let the expo generate my keysotre and I have a copy of the keystore. But in next release I chose expo to generate keystore again and now I have a new key store.

The problem is I don't have the old keystore password. fetch:android:keystore only gives me the new keystore password. Is there anyway I can fetch old keystore passwords from expo?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can contact Google Play Console Support on this issue and they will be able to reset the keystore for you.

In the play console click the help button at the top > Scroll down to heed more help and click "Contact Us" > Type in you need help with a Keystore Reset > Click "next step" > Click "Upload key reset request" > Click "Contact Google Play Developer Support" > Then choose a contact method to contact them to reset it for you.